# Is there any notable differences with the Adult Editions of Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, edition-comparison

So while I was going through my email, there was an email from Supernova about selling *"Harry Potter Series Adult Editions in Hardcover"*. Below is the image from the email, with the Harry Potter ad on the left.

[image: book ad]

I am wondering if there is any noticeable difference between these versions of the series and the original versions?

Comment: There is no difference, as far as the text goes. I've been wanting to pick up the versions of the books with the "adult" covers for a while now. I recently bought J.K. Rowling's bibliography and, man, there are a lot of different covers for this series.

Comment: @Slytherincess - do **NOT** google "Harry Potter"+"adult"... Word to the wise.